# MongoDB Compound Indexes - Does the sort order matter?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql, compound-index

I've dived recently into mongodb for a project of mine. 
I've been reading up on indexes, and for a small collection, i know it wouldn't matter much but when it grows there's going to be performance issues without the right indexes and queries.

Lets say i have a collection like so

```
{user_id:1,slug:'one-slug'}
{user_id:1,slug:'another-slug'}
{user_id:2,slug:'one-slug'}
{user_id:3,slug:'just-a-slug}
```

And i have to search my collection where

```
user id == 1 and slug == 'one-slug'
```

In this collection, slugs will be unique to user ids.
That is, user id 1 can have only one slug of the value 'one-slug'.

I understand that user_id should be given priority due to its high cardinality, but what about slug? Since its unique as well most of the time. I also cant wrap my head around ascending and descending indexes, or how its going to affect performance in this case or the right order i should be using in this collection.

I've read a bit but i can't wrap my head around it, particularly for my scenario. Would be awesome to hear from others.

Comment: sort order? But you're not doing any sorting.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev from the manual
"The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by values of the stock field."

Comment: Index direction only matters when you're sorting. [For example, `db.posts.find({user_id: 1}).order({slug: -1})`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields). For equality queries, index direction does not matter.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you, also im guessing that for my case, when i create the index, user id should be first. But can i bother you for an explanation as to the difference between {user_id:1,slug:1} and {slug:1,user_id:1}

Comment: Explanation for this is in the same section I linked to.

Comment: This blog post explains compound indexes clearly: https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/

Answer (score 14):

You can think of MongoDB single-field index as an array, with pointers to document locations. For example, if you have a collection with (note that the sequence is deliberately out-of-order):

```
[collection]
1: {a:3, b:2}
2: {a:1, b:2}
3: {a:2, b:1}
4: {a:1, b:1}
5: {a:2, b:2}
```

## Single-field index

Now if you do:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a:1})
```

The index approximately looks like:

```
[index a:1]
1: {a:1} --> 2, 4
2: {a:2} --> 3, 5
3: {a:3} --> 1
```

Note three important things:

- It's sorted by `a` ascending
- Each entry points to the location where the relevant documents resides
- The index only records the values of the `a` field. The `b` field does not exist in the index at all

So if you do a query like:

```
db.collection.find().sort({a:1})
```

All it has to do is to walk the index from top to bottom, fetching and outputting the document pointed to by the entries. Notice that you can also walk the index from the bottom, e.g.:

```
db.collection.find().sort({a:-1})
```

and the only difference is you walk the index in reverse.

Because `b` is not in the index at all, you cannot use the index when querying anything about `b`.

## Compound index

In a compound index e.g.:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a:1, b:1})
```

It means that you want to sort by `a` first, then sort by `b`. The index would look like:

```
[index a:1, b:1]
1: {a:1, b:1} --> 4
2: {a:1, b:2} --> 2
3: {a:2, b:1} --> 3
4: {a:2, b:2} --> 5
5: {a:3, b:2} --> 1
```

Note that:

- The index is sorted from `a`
- Within each `a` you have a sorted `b`
- You have 5 index entries vs. only three in the previous single-field example

Using this index, you can do a query like:

```
db.collection.find({a:2}).sort({b:1})
```

It can easily find where `a:2` then walk the index forward. **Given that index, you cannot do**:

```
db.collection.find().sort({b:1})
db.collection.find({b:1})
```

In both queries you can't easily find `b` since it's spread all over the index (i.e. not in contiguous entries). However you **can** do:

```
db.collection.find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})
```

since you can essentially find where the `a:2` are, and walk the `b` entries backward.

**Edit**: clarification of @marcospgp's question in the comment:

The possibility of using the index `{a:1, b:1}` to satisfy `find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})` actually make sense if you see it from a sorted table point of view. For example, the index `{a:1, b:1}` can be thought of as:

```
a | b
--|--
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 1
3 | 2
```

**find({a:2}).sort({b:1})**

The index `{a:1, b:1}` means `sort by a, then within each a, sort the b values`. If you then do a `find({a:2}).sort({b:1})`, the index knows where all the `a=2` are. Within this block of `a=2`, the `b` would be sorted in ascending order (according to the index spec), so that query `find({a:2}).sort({b:1})` can be satisfied by:

```
a | b
--|--
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1 <-- walk this block forward to satisfy
2 | 2 <-- find({a:2}).sort({b:1})
2 | 3 <--
3 | 1
3 | 2
```

**find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})**

Since the index can be walked forward or backwards, a similar procedure was followed, with a small twist at the end:

```
a | b
--|--
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1  <-- walk this block backward to satisfy
2 | 2  <-- find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})
2 | 3  <--
3 | 1
3 | 2
```

The fact that the index can be walked forward or backward is the key point that enables the query `find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})` to be able to use the index `{a:1, b:1}`.

## Query planner explain

You can see what the query planner plans by using `db.collection.explain().find(....)`. Basically if you see a `stage` of `COLLSCAN`, no index was used or can be used for the query. See [explain results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for details on the command's output.

Comment: According to the manual this answer is incorrect. You couldn't "find where the `a: 2` are, and walk the `b` entries backward". It does seem a little silly, as in why does the index have to be linear? Just nest the values right? But it seems that's how it was built: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order

Comment: @marcospgp How did you come to this conclusion? You can check if my answer correctness by `db.collection.explain().find({a:1}).sort({b:-1})`. If you see `COLLSCAN` in the output, that means the index is **not** used. If you see `IXSCAN` instead, the index **is** used.

Comment: It's what it says on the link I included. Maybe the docs are wrong

Comment: @marcospgp do you mind pointing out which part in the docs that you refer to? I'm trying to understand your point of view. Granted, the case I was putting in the answer was actually a nuanced one, since the example in the docs is using both fields to sort, while I used only one of the field to sort.

Comment: Your example is slightly different from the docs, and the docs don't mention that kind of situation. Still I would expect that since you can't sort by `{ a: 1, b: -1 }` that you also wouldn't be able to sort by `{ b: -1 }` after querying with a particular `a`. Not sure! The docs are less specific than they should be.

Comment: @marcospgp I have provided further explanation in the answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: So `find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})` could make use of the index while `find().sort({ a: 1, b:-1})` couldn't?

Comment: @marcospgp yes. See the table I posted and try imagining a linear path forward or backward through the index for `sort({a:1, b:-1})`. It cannot be done since you have to go back and forth in the index. But if you do `find({a:2}).sort({b:-1})`, you can just get to the block where `a=2` is true, and walk a linear path through the index.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I use Mongoose 5 to assign indices to keys, when I do `getIndexes()` in Mongo Shell, the order of indices matches the order of keys in the schema file. However, if I query the last key which also comes with the last index and do a `explain()`, the index is still being used. How would Mongoose in-key index true different from `createIndex()` and what would be index usage best practice in MongoDB? Thanks.

Comment: @TriNguyen do you mind creating a new question? That sounds like something specific to what you are doing. It's best to examine the facts on its own question.

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot comment due to a lack of reputation]

> Index direction only matters when you're sorting.

Not completely exact : some queries can be faster with particular direction index, even if no order is required in the query itself (sorting is just for results). For example, queries with date criteria : searching for users who subscribe yesterday will be faster with a desc direction on index, than with asc direction or no index.

> difference between {user_id:1,slug:1} and {slug:1,user_id:1}

mongo will filter on first field, then on second field with first field matching (and so on...) in index. The more restrictive fields must be at first places to really improve the query