# How index is different in mongodb and mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, indexing

I am reading about indexes in mongodb. I am able to create one on a particular field. But i have a few doubts in mind on how it works. In sql, u create an index on a column in a table. So the entries in that column will be indexed whenever they are inserted. How does it work in mongodb? Lets say i inserted the following document in mongodb :

```
user_id:111
name:"abc"
balance:146
```

I then indexed the field **name** . If i insert a new document:

```
user_id : 222
name : "xyz"
balance:123
```

How does this proceed now ? **Also explain me in the context of mongodb being unstructured compared to sql. To be in detail if i use the same field name in some other document in a different context, how does this affect ?** I hope i am clear about the question, if any details missing, please mention.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171783/mongodb-compound-indexes-does-the-sort-order-matter/51184129#51184129, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886279/mongo-query-take-a-long-time-how-make-it-more-fast/49934916#49934916, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196 answer your question?

Comment: With MongoDB, you have to re-invent the non-trivial parts of Indexing that are provided by default in MySQL and other real databases.  (I wonder how much flack I will get for this Comment?!)

Comment: @kevinadi , they did not answer my question. My question is about how mongodb takes new data of an indexed field in the context of mongodb being unstructured database. I insist you to read the question once more please.